# how to display object based on matching object id with the id coming from the server

Tags: node.js, angularjs, angular, typescript

I have an array of objects like this :

in FruitModel.ts

```
export interface ColorByFruit{  
    Id : number;
    name : string;
    color : string;
}  
  const Fruits: ColorByFruit[] = [  
     {Id:1, name:"Apple", color:"red"},
     {Id:2, name:"Banana", color:"yellow"}, 
     {Id:3, name:"Peach", color:"Orange"},
     {Id:4, name:"Pineapple", color:"Brown"},
     {Id:5, name:"Blueberry", color:"blue"}, 
];
```

in the class.ts
I import the interface into the class

then I get data from the server which includes an ID, I want to match the ID ith the colorFruit Id so I can display the name of the fruit and the color.

how do I do that ?

Comment: You import an interface in a consctructor ???
Based on what you say, try this:
 
`const names = ServerFruits.filter(x => Fruits.map(y => y.Id).includes(x.Id)).map(x => x.name);`

Comment: do you have a way to match the ids . based on the matching you display the name and the color ?

Comment: injecting it was wrong, sorry,

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solved your problem

Answer (score 1):

To display the name and color you just have to use the map operator.

Suppose your list of fruits coming from the server are set in a variable : **ServerFruits**

```
const nameAndColors = ServerFruits.filter(x => Fruits.map(y => y.Id).includes(x.Id)).map(({Id, name}) => ({Id, name})); 

console.log(nameAndColors );
```

Comment: where you got filter function from ?

Comment: you should google **filter** and you will get your answer